# simple puzzle IQ-test question

Tags: pattern

[image]What is the next piece and why?

[image: ! What is the next piece and why?]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE ! This doesn't seem like your puzzle, do you mind also including the source and making sure that you have permission to share it?

Comment: Only post a single question in one. It becomes more complicated to determine who is right when you are asking multiple questions at once that should be split up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say

> B

because

> the entire image is reflected, then the number of rectangles at the (flipped) left is doubled and the image on the right is duplicated below it.

To the added parts:

> #1 is B also, the top part is reflected across the y-axis while the bottom across the x-axis.

and

> #2 is C because the first triangle is the bottom right, the second is the bottom left, and 3rd is the top

Answer (score 0):

I will go with

> **B**

Explanation:

> We see that the triangle is doubled and that they add a new line in the middle of each rectangle.